# What is wrong in my martingale calculations in this exercise?

Tags: generating-functions, conditional-expectation, martingales

I am trying to solve this Martingale exercise which states that :
Consider the simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ and the function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z},f(k)=k^4$.

Show that : $Lf(k)=6k^2+1 $ and prove that the process $\{M_{n}\}_{n \in N_{0}}$ with  $M_{0}=0$ and $$M_{n}=X_{n}^4-X_{n}^2-6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_{k}^2,\quad \forall n \in N$$ is a martingale.

**My effort:**

For $f(k) =k^4$ , the generator of the chain:
$$ Lf(x)=0 \Rightarrow  \frac{f(x+1)+f(x-1)}{2} -f(x)=0 $$

becomes:

\begin{align*}
 Lf(k)&  =  \frac{f(k+1)+f(k-1)}{2} -f(k)\\
  & =  \frac{f(k+1)^4+f(k-1)^4}{2} -f(k)^4\\
  &= \frac{  (k^4 + 4k^3+6k^2 +4k +1)  + (k^4 - 4k^3+6k^2 -4k +1) }{ 2 }  -k^4 \\
  & = \frac{2k^4 +12k^2+2}{2} -k^4\\
  & = k^4 +6k^2 +1 -k^4\\
  & = 6k^2 +1
  \end{align*}

For the stochastic process $\{M_{n }\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}$ with $M_{0}=0$ and $$M_{n}=X_{n}^4-X_{n}^2-6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} X_{k}^2$$
we have :

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ M_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]  &= \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1}^4  - X_{n+1}^2 -6 \sum_{k=0}^{n} X_{k}^2\mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] \\
&=  \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1}^4 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] -  \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1}^2 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] - 6\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left[ \mathbb{E} \left[ (X_{n} -X_{n-1})^2 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] \right] \\
& = \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n}^4 + 4X_{n}^3 X_{n+1} +6X_{n}^2 X_{n+1} + 4X_{n}X_{n+1}^3 +X_{n+1}^4 \mid  \mathbb{F}_{n}\right]\\
& -  \mathbb{E}\left[ X_{n+1}^{2}\mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] - 6\left[ \mathbb{E}[X_{0}^2] + \mathbb{E}\left[X_{n}^{2} - X_{n-1}^{2} + 2 X_{n}^2X_{n-1} \mid  \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]  \right] \\
&=X_{n}^4 +4X_{n}^3 \underbrace{ \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]}_{0} +6x_{n}^2 \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1}^2 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]}_{1} + 4X_{n} \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1}^3 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]}_{0} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n+1}^4 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]}_{1} \\
&+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{n}^2 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] +   \underbrace{  \mathbb{E}\left[ X_{n+1}^{2}\mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]}_{1}+  \mathbb{E}\left[2X_{n}X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right] -6 \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[X_{0}^2 \right]}_{0} + 6   \mathbb{E} \left[X_{n}^2 \mid \mathbb{F}_{n}\right]  - \underbrace{6 \mathbb{E}\left[X_{n-1}^2\mid \mathbb{F}_{n} \right]}_{1}   \\ 
&=  X_{n}^4 +0+ 6X_{n}^{2} +0+1 + X_{n}^2+1 +2X_{n}\underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[X_{n+1} \mid \mathbb{F}_{n}\right]}_{0} -0 + 6X_{n}^2 -6   \\
& =X_{n}^4 +6X_{n}^2 +1 + X_{n}^{2} +1 + 6X_{n}^{2} -6 \\
&= X_{n}^4 +X_{n}^2- 4
\end{align*}

I have made something very wrong here and i don't know what.Any help ?

Comment: Is $X_k$ the simple random walk itself, or $X_k=\sum_{i=1}^k \xi_i$, where $\xi_i=\pm 1$ with probability $1$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo if $\mathbb{E}[ M_{n+1}-M_{n}|F_{n}]=0$

Comment: Correctness of your approach depends on what $X_k$ is. By the way, you have a typo at the very first line of $\mathbb E\left[M_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n\right]$: the sum of the $X_k^2$ should stop at $n$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo $X_{k}$ are the i.i.d  sequence of random variables in the random walk. I have correct it  the $n-1$ issue.

Comment: So if $E[(X_{n})^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}] = 1 $ the rest is changing.Leaving the quadratic expansion...